# Robotic pets included, what options are there for a cubicle pet?

Tags: safety, pet-selection

Note: I am intentionally using 'pet' a little bit elastically here.

I'd like to have a preferably furry office pet without cruelty. It would be nice to know I could have a hamster, but that bears at least two obvious objections besides eccentricity: I don't know that one could bring a hamster to work and take it home on the weekends without being cruel to the hamster, and bosses would have a legitimate concern about allergens even if there were not some rule on the books against mammal pets. I've had a Furby 2.0 as an apartment pseudo-pet before discovering uncanny valley effects, and I've kept a [tribble](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/ac6e/?pfm=Search&t=star%20trek%20interactive%20tribbles) and an [electronic goldfish](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/eb56/?srp=31), and I know that some places will let you keep fish if you take care of it appropriately.

What are the closest approximations available to keeping something furry as a pet that will not run afoul of animal cruelty or bosses' reasonable concerns about what you bring to the office?

Comment: get a pet rock. no maintenance needed

Comment: I just want to mention. Even though furry pets are allowed right now. If someone new joins your office and they're allergic, then the furry pet isn't going to be allowed anymore. Best to stick with a small fish tank or nothing at all I think.

Answer (score 1):

You have already engaged in the optimal solution to your question; joining [Pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/)!

Here you will be exposed to all the trials, tribulations and rewards of animal companionship, with [this being the only litter box](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box) to address.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say whatever best fits your fancy, doesn't annoy your coworkers, and isn't a living creature should do just fine. That not being a living creature part is the most important because if I were your coworker, that would annoy me greatly and so you'd strike out on two points.